# Stop a xml block from displaying unless called in phtml file

Tags: checkout, blocks

ok we're running several affiliate networks and we don't want to end up paying 2 lots of commission in case the customer has been through 2 separate networks affiliate. As such we have a 'last source' custom cookie that's created so when we get to checkout/success.phtml it will only display 1 lot of conversion tracking code.

all our tracking codes are setup in separate .phtml files to keep success.phtml as clean as possible.

On our 'success.phtml' we have this code:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie_name'])):

if($_COOKIE['cookie_name'] == 'Affiliate1'):
    echo $this->getAffiliateOne();
elseif($_COOKIE['cookie_name'] == 'Affiliate2'):
    echo $this->getAffiliateTwo();
endif;

// Do Both Tracking Codes
else:
echo $this->getAffiliateOne();
echo $this->getAffiliateTwo();
endif;
```

and our checkout.xml says:

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml">

        <block name="affiliate_one" template="checkout/tracking/affiliate_one_tracking.phtml" type="checkout/onepage_success" /><!-- Affiliate 1 -->
    <block name="affiliate_two" template="checkout/tracking/affiliate_two_tracking.phtml" type="checkout/onepage_success"/><!-- Affiliate 2 -->

 </block>
    </reference>
```

how ever even though the cookie part is working it seems to auto display both tracking codes. I've tested it by removing all the phtml additions and it still displays all the tracking code regardless. What do i need to do to the checkout.xml so it make sure it only displays the block if it's requested for in the phtml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `content` block you're adding your affiliate blocks to is a `text/list` block.  A `text/list` block will render **all** children added to it.   If I was implementing this, I'd add a new template block to content via `local.xml` (**not** by editing the `catalog.xml` file, but that's up to you. )

```
<!-- File: app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/layout/local.xml -->
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="affiliate_master" template="affiliate_master.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Then I'd add two my two child blocks to this master blocks, again via `local.xml`

```
<!-- File: app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/layout/local.xml -->
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="affiliate_master" template="affiliate_master.phtml"/>
</reference>

<reference name="affiliate_master">
    <block name="affiliate_one" template="checkout/tracking/affiliate_one_tracking.phtml" type="checkout/onepage_success" /><!-- Affiliate 1 -->
    <block name="affiliate_two" template="checkout/tracking/affiliate_two_tracking.phtml" type="checkout/onepage_success"/><!-- Affiliate 2 -->
</reference>
```

And finally, in my new `affiliate_master.phtml`, I'd be able to output the blocks with

```
#File: app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/template/affiliate_master.phtml

echo $this->getChildHtml('affiliate_one');
echo $this->getChildHtml('affiliate_two');
```

Adding whatever special logic I wanted to around the calls to `getChildHtml`.

(the above is untested, quickly dashed off code that may not be correct, but the general concept is sound)

Comment: text/list ahhh that's the ticket. :)

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for your input, this seems to have done the trick. Because my code was purely for 'checkout success' so i wrapped it in `<checkout_onepage_success>
</checkout_onepage_success>` and placed it in my local.xml

Comment: @AndyArcher Ah, yes, I should have been explicit about that.  All the layout code above should be wrapped in a handle (like checkout_onepage_success) of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

Gosh - it's amazing how many businesses have similar rules regarding affiliates and last-touch. But, I digress...

You have a number of issues here:

**Child Blocks:**

This line:

```
$this->getAffiliateOne();
```

Does not output a child block. Rather, it is trying to echo the property named `affiliate_one` on the `checkout/onepage_success` block. That's not what you wanted, I'm sure. As a method of debugging if you were to `var_dump` instead of echo you'd see that it outputs `null` or `false`.

Rather, you need to do the following:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('affiliate_one');
```

**Core Block Template**

My guess of *why* it's displaying the two pixels regardless of your logic is because your blocks are extending `Mage_Core_Block_Template` or `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Success` is, which is forcing it to auto-render. This is not what you want. Make sure your blocks extend `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` instead and use the above `getChildHtml` call to invoke your logic.

**$_COOKIE**

Instead of using PHP superglobals, rather, use Magento's wrappers:

```
$cookie = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('cookie_name');
```

Comment: Thanks Phil, the cookie suggestion i've now implemented :)    I think i'm potentially being thick/clueless but i couldn't seem to get your solution to work. However i think you're right on that the phtml file wasn't actually having any hand in getting the tracking to appear